# Is the state change for flags automatic in cases where the question gets marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, helpful-flags

There are two questions that I have:

1. I am not sure why my name did not appear as someone who has marked the question as duplicate. Although after I marked the question as duplicate, I saw it appearing on comments with my id. But once it was accepted as duplicate both the comment and my name did not appear.
2. It is marked as helpful flag. But I am not sure if it was reviewed manually or automatically.

Example:

[Compare two date of type String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641101/compare-a-date-with-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have less than 3,000 rep, you cannot cast [close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) yet. This means that

1. When you flag a post as a duplicate, this will generate a comment, and put the question in the review queue. The flag does not count against the 5 close votes needed for closing the question. When the question is closed, the names of the 5 close voters will appear. This will also delete the auto-generated comment.
2. Your flag is already marked helpful when the first close vote is cast - so it is a manual action by a >3k-user, *usually* not a moderator.